# Updating angular model with ng-change

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My goal is very simply to be able to update a model that I am binding too, after its value has been updated with JQuery. I am working with some fairly fixed legacy code, so I can't really do it the good old fashioned angular way (see below).

**VERY IMPORTANT:** I do not have the ability to use the ng-repeat, ng-options on the select field. The value of the options is tied to corresponding IDs--I can't change the format of that data. I can add new directives to these elements if necessary. I apologize in advance for these constraints..

Here is what I have now:

**HTML**

```
<select id="animalSelection" ng-change="forceApply(my.animal)">
  <option value="1">Dog</option>
  <option value="2">Cat</option>
  <option value="3">Zebra</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="animalSelected" ng-model="my.animal" />

<h1>Selected Animal: {{my.animal}}</h1>
```

**JS**

```
// Get text of selected option
var animal = $("#animalSelection option:selected").text();

// Updates hidden input with ng-model attribute
$("#animalSelected").val(animal);
```

**Controller Function:**

```
// I know this part is for sure wrong.. really needs help

$scope.forceApply = function(applymodel){
   $scope.$apply(applymodel);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom directive for this:

**angular**

```
app.directive('myChange', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      //the ng-model you want to modify
      myModel: '=' 
    },
    link: function (scope, ele) {
      // sets first value on load
      scope.myModel = ele.find(':first').text();
      ele.bind('change', function () {
        // applies scope change
        scope.myModel = ele.find(':selected').text();
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**html**

```
<select id="animalSelection" data-my-model="my.animal" data-my-change>
  <option value="1">Dog</option>
  <option value="2">Cat</option>
  <option value="3">Zebra</option>
</select>

<input type="hidden" id="animalSelected" ng-model="my.animal" />

<h1>Selected Animal: {{my.animal}}</h1>
```

**plunkr:** http://plnkr.co/edit/Z8tWQHDJWtPN6Yrjwu3a?p=preview

Comment: That did it! You are my personal Jesus.